# make a specific view move when keyboard appear with fab

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, view, floating-action-button

i'm trying to stop the recycle view to be above the toolbar when i try to search and keyboard shows meanwhile make the fab visible(above the keyboard) ... i have tried adjustResize and the adjustpan and stateAlwaysHiddenand toghther in manifast it doesn't work so i want the recycle to be blocked and shows the fab after keyboard show

Comment: Show your relevant code pls

Comment: @VivekGupta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73558654/stop-a-specific-views-moving-when-the-keyboard-shows